Confidence intervals around treatment effect in stratified experiment
Suppose you conduct an experiment, where a population is randomized and treatment is given to the treatment group and you are interested in covariates (stratification has been employed) and their interaction with treatment exposure.
To put this in context, suppose the outcome of interest is 1-mile run time, treatment exposure is consuming gatorade within 1hr of run and covariate is height, weight and sex (stratified).
I believe that this model could be specified as
$runTime_{i} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 treatmentGroup_{i} + \beta_2weight_{i} + \beta_3 treatmentGroup_{i}weight_{i} + \beta_4 height_{i} + \beta_5 treatmentGroup_{i} height_{i} 
 + \beta_6 sex_{i} + \beta_7 treatmentGroup_{i}sex_{i}$
Some questions

Assuming that the group of individuals is well randomized, there is no need to condition on pre-exposure period - correct? (unlike DiD where means may differ but parallel trends are assumed)

How can I extract the tangible the main effects and interaction in terms of seconds? I'm not asking about the coefficients per se but rather the expected increase/decrease in run time seconds attributable to each coefficient and the bias.

Are simulations necessary to extract the effect of weight on run time? The treatment group coefficient is binary, so it should already be in terms of seconds. But I may need to use the average from the distribution of weights to extract the effect of weight in terms of seconds (likewise for weight treatment interaction.)

How can I compute confidence intervals around the outputs of [2, 3]?

Are ANOVA and F-statistic the correct way to determine significance of each main effects and interaction?

How can confidence intervals be constructed around the coefficients? (Aka - Disregarding tangible effects on run time for a moment, are these coefficients significant?)

What if by some quirk during randomization, the means and variances are not even, does this need to be corrected for or negligible? (Presumably there's a heuristic threshold)

Assuming that the estimators do require correction, how?


Thank you in advance!

Taking your questions in turn:

Adjusting for pre-experiment run-times is not strictly necessary in a randomized experiment, but you'd want to do it, because it makes inference more efficient (because there's lots of variation in run-times between people, but less in the same person from occasion to occasion).
I'm not sure why you think you could find out the bias in an estimate (or of the estimator in general). It is in general hard to tell whether your particular combination of experiment + analysis has resulted in a bias. Regarding "tangible main effects" - how do you think those differ from the coefficients (especially since this appears to be a linear model)? Do you mean treatment effects averaged across the population?
The coefficient for weight is already in seconds per weight unit. Do you want to simulate to average across the population distribution (where sex and weight would not usually be independent) to say something like "on average in this population, a random person drinking gatorade will run so fast"? Does your experiment match that kind of inference (i.e. is it a representative sample of people from the population you are interested in, or is it not randomly selected from the population but rather a really non-representative sample like volunteers answering a newspaper advert or a flyer on an information board at a university?) Or do you want to somehow average across "posterior uncertainty" to account for the point estimate being uncertain?
Depending on exactly what you really want to do, there's probably software implementations for any of those things. The biostatistics community has probably implementation most things you can think of in these respects in some R package. There's probably also publications on most variants, e.g. if you want population average effects, that's extensively discussed in a FDA guidance on covariate adjustment in randomized trials with commentaries available in various places (e.g. here or here).
You'd want to do linear regression as the overarching concept that can answer all these questions and there's nice helper tools to let you ask about hypotheses you want to test / contrasts you want to evaluate (e.g. the emmeans R package).
Software will usually give you confidence intervals.
Ideally, you'd want to know this up-front based on the literature. Testing the assumptions of a model on the same data as you do your inference on is problematic and tends to lead to problems. On the other hand, if the assumption in truth hold and you have an unlucky sample, you are theoretically fine (but how do you know that, prior data would presumably what you turn to...). It might of course be unavoidable, if you were the first person to ever do a study on run-times. In practice, yes, some small deviations from the assumptions of linear regression are non-problematic and larger ones problematic and there's rules of thumb. E.g. I would think up-front variances would not be homogeneous. World-class athletes do not have that much variation in e.g. their 100 m sprint times, while untrained amateurs would typically have much more variation in their performance. Of course, you can run models that relax all kinds of assumptions (e.g. you could let the variance depend on the previous run-times of the person or their sex). If you want to assess whether small deviations from assumptions would really be a problem, you might need to simulate under reasonable assumptions an see what happens.
Correction for what? For most of the correction one might want to do, methods have likely been proposed and implemented in some R package.


[2] and [3] were hinting at the same question and you detected it- yes, I’m curious about the frequentist analog for credible interval around a point estimate. But without a posterior distribution, is this possible?

Regarding [1] how would you adjust for pre-experiment run times? I’m only aware of DiD methodology but perhaps that’s just one of many approaches

Re 1) A common approach in randomized controlled trials is to do covariate adjustment (i.e. use a regression model and one covariate is the pre-experiment measurement, or a pre-intervention measurement in the experiment). It so happens that for linear regression in randomized trials measurement error in the pre-measurement does not cause issues. It's also the case that once you adjust for it, you can analyze the absolute end of study values or the change vs. pre-intervention and you can numerically the same treatment differences.

2/3) You could always do a Bayesian analysis. Alternatively, sort of pretend that you did by treating the sampling distribution around the ML estimate for model parameters (for the combined parameters often asymptotically a multivariate normal - e.g. linear models fit with R would give you the coefficients as the mean vector and the estimated covariance matrix via the vcov function) like a posterior. Not saying this is a good idea & depends on what you want if this changes anything other than the SE of some quantity you calculate (mostly makes a difference under non-linear transformations).
